# TYPO3 and RealUrl don't use translated page titles in url

Tags: typo3, realurl, typo3-7.1.x

I use TYPO3 7.1 and RealUrl 1.13.3.
Auto configuration is not using the page title from translated pages and it is not changing ?L=1 to fx /en/

It is just using the default Danish page titles and adding ?L=1 to English pages and ?L=2 to German pages.

The content is shown in the right languages.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First switch to manual config, then add config for `L` param in `preVars` section according to your languages [like described in doc](https://wiki.typo3.org/Realurl/manual#Example:_Language_prefix_and_.22admin.22_action)

```php
     array(
         'GETvar' => 'L',
         'valueMap' => array(
             'dk' => '1',
             'en' => '2',
             // etc...
         ),
         'noMatch' => 'bypass',
     ),
```

also add the `languageGetVar` (also [described in doc](https://wiki.typo3.org/Realurl/manual#Configure_.22realurl.22_to_work_with_.22tx_realurl_advanced.22_ID_encoding)) param to `pagePath` section

```php
'pagePath' => array(
    'type' => 'user',
    'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
    'rootpage_id' => 1,
    'languageGetVar' => 'L', // <- here
),
```

Comment: That didn't change anything. If I try www.domain.dk/en/ I get the English version. But links are still wrong. You can see realurl_conf and my language navigation typoscript here: http://pastebin.com/8GefSJEj

Comment: Your sample works for me, maybe RealURL cache? clear the tables with RU cache manually (truncate DONT'T delete) also make sure you switched to manual config (and delete *_autoconf.php), then clear all caches from Install tool. btw you're missing part in news section, read this article and add mentioned 4 lines: http://davdenic.com/how-to-set-up-correctly-realurl-tt-news-and-language/ __IMPORTANT in new News ext that should be:__ `'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',`