# What configuration needed for realURL to allow to add language based speaking url?

Tags: typo3, realurl, typo3-7.6.x

I have developed an application based on typo3, in this i need to set the speaking url based on active languages (de/en), right now they are creating for same alias (default language) for both language. How can i configure to use german alias for de and english alias for en ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 and RealUrl don't use translated page titles in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982342/typo3-and-realurl-dont-use-translated-page-titles-in-url)

Comment: Hi Rob, this issue is fixed.. thanks for commenting.